# why does other have read permissions by default on files/folders?

Tags: linux, permissions

I have noticed that on any default/standard installation of *nix any new files/folders automatically get, at minimum, `read` permissions on `other`.

Why is this? Isn't this insecure? Shouldn't *nix systems give no default permissions to `other` by default? Wouldn't that be more secure?

It makes sense you want the `user` to have access to the file/folder (duh) and it is understandable why `group` should have access.

But what benefit is there with `other` having access by default?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A multi-user operating system like Unix gains more benefits from sharing files than it gains in security by locking everything down hard by default.   There's a trade-off between security and convenience. In practice, the default settings are typically used well and are a good compromise.

You can always make permissions on a folder more secure.  `chmod 750 ./FOLDER` will give Read, Write and Execute permissions to the owner with the 7, Read and Execute permissions to the group with the 5, and no permissions to the other group.

If you look at the `/etc/` folder, where a lot of configuration settings are stored, the permissions allow Read and Execute to other:

```
vagrant@host:~$ ls -ld /etc/
drwxr-xr-x 136 root root 12288 Dec  6 12:48 /etc/
vagrant@host:~$
```

The idea here is that it can actually *help* operation of the system. For example, the apache web server, running as user **apache**, can read its configuration files.  However, the configuration files are owned by root, so if a bad actor gets hold of the **apache** user, that account cannot write new permissions for itself.

Linux (and Unix) systems are designed to be multi-user Operating Systems.  Having **other** users read files by default is more helpful more often than it is a security issue.  Sometimes you want members of a team (your **group**) to be able to edit files, too; so you set `chmod g+rwx ./FOLDER` which allows members of the **group** to edit files in that folder.

The permissions system is flexible enough to tune this to your needs.  The [Linux Documentation Project](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/intro-linux/html/sect_03_04.html) explains it well, and has great examples. [Security-Enhanced Linux](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Security-Enhanced_Linux) extends it even more.

I suggest you take a look at unix.stackexchange.com in particular the tag marked Permissions where a number of questions are answered in good detail.  In particular:

1. [How do directory permissions in Linux work?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/21251/how-do-directory-permissions-in-linux-work)
2. [How to set default file permissions for all folders/files in a directory?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/1314/how-to-set-default-file-permissions-for-all-folders-files-in-a-directory)

---

Answer (score 0):

Programs which create new files defines their permissions. Permissions given to a newly created file from a shell is often restricted to `rwxr-xr-x` which is the default [`umask`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Umask) on most Linux distributions.

You can edit your private login scripts such as `~/.bashrc`, or system-wide `/etc/profile` scripts to edit this default `umask` and give it a more restrictive value. But most of the time it is okay to keep it as is since you are likely to have all your private files in your home directory. You only need to check your home directory permissions to block unwanted users from listing *(`r`)* and traversing *(`x`)* it.

---

On my Linux system, this default behavior is defined in `/etc/profile`:

```bsh
# 077 would be more secure, but 022 is generally quite realistic  
umask 022
```